# Getting Data from foreign table by primary key

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

In this setup, I have one Owner and he has 10 schools. I get the list of Owners in a combo box and select the Owner with its Id using `combox.selectedvalue` and name using its text value. Now I have a data grid view in which I want to list all the schools which belongs to selected owners with an additional column of owner name that is in the Owner table in data grid view.

I want to do this using Entity Framework.

[image: Two Tables with Owner as primary key table and School as a Foreign key]

[image: Form]

I have seen many questions here but I didn't find exactly what I need.

Comment: Have you mapped the tables to entities?

Comment: Yes i have mapped using Entity model. That is why i am able to get a list of Owners in the combo box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your schema for the database

Try this in event `ComboBoxOwner_SelectedIndexChanged()`

```
var selectedOwner = ((Owner)ComboBoxOwner.SelectedItem).Id;


GridViewSchools.DataSource = (from school in DbContext.Schools
                              join owner in DbContext.Owners on school.OwnerId equals owner.Id
                              where school.OwnerId == selectedOwner
                              select new { schoolName= school.Name , OwnerName = owner.Name }).ToList();
```

you can add all information of school at the same method

[image]